# How can I filter and count the lines into a variable in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to figure something out, and this late at night I'm getting nowhere. The command `docker ps -a` gives the following output.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
21cf52afa3d0        mysql:5.7           "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   Less than a second ago   Up 1 seconds        0.0.0.0:3307->3306/tcp   irrelevant-name
073795442e02        mysql:5.7           "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   Less than a second ago   Created                                      someother-mysql
cb1952b0e5ed        mysql:5.7           "/entrypoint.sh mysql"   3 minutes ago            Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   heist-mysql
```

What I want to do is count how many lines contain `-mysql`, and store it in a variable (in the above case, the value would be `2`) so I can use it later on.

I've seen a few things about `Select-String`, but so far nothing I've thrown together works. I've tried things like `docker ps -a | Select-String -Pattern ("*-mysql")`, but so far everything has given me an error.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the results from the `docker` command parse similar to `Get-Content`, try this:

```
(docker ps -a | Select-String -Pattern "-MySQL" | Measure-Object).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

All PowerShell commands generate Objects.  If you don't store the object in a variable or pass it to another command, PowerShell converts the object to a text representation before it shows the result to you.  Select-String doesn't seem to work on the object type returned from the `docker ps` command.

try `docker ps -a | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -Pattern (".*-mysql")`